# PHP Not redirecting - No error?

Tags: php, redirect

I've added the piece of code that redirects me to another page.
But it doesn't redirect me at all?
The codes executes fine, no blank pages nor error messages. Which i think is very strange.
So I don't see what could be wrong.

What is this, and how to fix it?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ingameban']))
{
//recompose the banlist
$cache_ig = "banlist_cache.txt";
$fh = fopen($cache_ig, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$contents = $_POST['text'];
fwrite($fh, $contents);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM banlist");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$uid = $row['uid'];
$player = $row['Player'];
$admin = $row['Admin'];
$bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
$unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
$reason = $row['Reason'];
$pin_db = $row['PIN'];
$content = "\n";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $uid;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " # ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $admin;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " banned ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $player;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " on ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $bannedon;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " reason ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $reason;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " unbanned on ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $unbanned;
fwrite($fh, $content);
} 

fclose($fh);    
?>
<?php
header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
die();
?>
```

The code executes fine, apart from redirecting.

```
header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
    die();
```

Thank you

Comment: *" No error?"* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: `header()` needs to be the first thing done before there is any output sent. You can get around it by doing a redirect by echoing JavaScript.

Comment: Plus, you're overwriting your content.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: file in /var/www/new-banlist.php on line 49

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/new-banlist.php on line 49

Comment: `$content = "\n$uid # $admin banned $player on $bannedon reason $reason unbanned on $unbanned";` I just want you to know that you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The first, obvious thing is that you are missing a closing }

-- code formatting is your friend,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ingameban']))
{
//recompose the banlist
    $cache_ig = "banlist_cache.txt";
    $fh = fopen($cache_ig, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $contents = $_POST['text'];
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM banlist");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $uid = $row['uid'];
        $player = $row['Player'];
        $admin = $row['Admin'];
        $bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
        $unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
        $reason = $row['Reason'];
        $pin_db = $row['PIN'];
        $content = "\n";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $uid;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = " # ";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $admin;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = " banned ";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $player;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = " on ";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $bannedon;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = " reason ";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $reason;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = " unbanned on ";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        $content = $unbanned;
        fwrite($fh, $content);
    } 

    fclose($fh);    
    header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
    die();
    ?>
```

The next thing is that you don't need to do this:

```
$uid = $row['uid'];
$player = $row['Player'];
$admin = $row['Admin'];
$bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
$unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
$reason = $row['Reason'];
$pin_db = $row['PIN'];
$content = "\n";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $uid;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " # ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $admin;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " banned ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $player;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " on ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $bannedon;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " reason ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $reason;
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = " unbanned on ";
fwrite($fh, $content);
$content = $unbanned;
fwrite($fh, $content);
```

you can replace all of that with:

```
$uid = $row['uid'];
$player = $row['Player'];
$admin = $row['Admin'];
$bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
$unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
$reason = $row['Reason'];
$pin_db = $row['PIN'];

$content = "\n" . "$content $uid # $admin banned $player on $bannedon reason $reason unbanned on $unbanned";
fwrite($fh, $content);
```

Which gives:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ingameban']))
{
//recompose the banlist
    $cache_ig = "banlist_cache.txt";
    $fh = fopen($cache_ig, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $contents = $_POST['text'];
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM banlist");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $uid = $row['uid'];
        $player = $row['Player'];
        $admin = $row['Admin'];
        $bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
        $unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
        $reason = $row['Reason'];
        $pin_db = $row['PIN'];

        $content = "\n" . "$content $uid # $admin banned $player on $bannedon reason $reason unbanned on $unbanned";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
    } 

    fclose($fh);    
    header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Now you can get to debugging:

1) header wont redirect if there is anything on the page: you have an echo, so change it to a die()

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ingameban']))
{
//recompose the banlist
    $cache_ig = "banlist_cache.txt";
    $fh = fopen($cache_ig, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $contents = $_POST['text'];
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM banlist");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $uid = $row['uid'];
        $player = $row['Player'];
        $admin = $row['Admin'];
        $bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
        $unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
        $reason = $row['Reason'];
        $pin_db = $row['PIN'];

        $content = "\n" . "$content $uid # $admin banned $player on $bannedon reason $reason unbanned on $unbanned";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
    } 

    fclose($fh);    
    header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Then you can add the debug level code from the comment:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['ingameban']))
{
//recompose the banlist
    $cache_ig = "banlist_cache.txt";
    $fh = fopen($cache_ig, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $contents = $_POST['text'];
    fwrite($fh, $contents);
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM banlist");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $uid = $row['uid'];
        $player = $row['Player'];
        $admin = $row['Admin'];
        $bannedon = $row['Bannedon'];
        $unbanned = $row['Unbanned'];
        $reason = $row['Reason'];
        $pin_db = $row['PIN'];

        $content = "\n" . "$content $uid # $admin banned $player on $bannedon reason $reason unbanned on $unbanned";
        fwrite($fh, $content);
    } 

    fclose($fh);    
    header("Location: new-ban_upload.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

And now it should tell you whats wrong